Showing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left ( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{(n-j)^2}-x^{(n+j-1)^2}}{(2n-1)(2j-1)} \right ) = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$

Show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left ( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{(n-j)^2}-x^{(n+j-1)^2}}{(2n-1)(2j-1)} \right) = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

I liked this problem because the result is a final answer, and not a function or an answer with a variable! It's rare to find such beautiful problems
Would like to share my solution if it is not prohibited and look at other solutions. I'm more interested in knowing if there are exotic ways to solve this problem? For example, through special functions or some approximations and so on
Solution:
\begin{align*}
S=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left ( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{(n-j)^2}-x^{(n+j-1)^2}}{(2n-1)(2j-1)} \right )=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left [ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{(n-j)^2}}{(2n-1)(2j-1)}-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^{(n+j-1)^2}}{(2n-1)(2j-1)}\right ]=\\=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left [ \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\left [ \frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2j-1} \right ]\frac{x^{(n-j)^2}}{2(j-n)}-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\left [ \frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2j-1} \right ]\frac{x^{(n+j-1)^2}}{2(n+j-1)} \right ]\\=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}-\\-&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left [ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\left [ \frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2j-1} \right ]\frac{x^{(n-j)^2}}{n-j}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\left [ \frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2j-1} \right ]\frac{x^{(n+j-1)^2}}{n+j-1} \right ]=\\=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}-S_1
\end{align*}
\begin{align}
S_1=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2n-1}\left [ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{(n-j)^2}}{n-j}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{(n+j-1)^2}}{n+j-1} \right ]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2n-1}\left [ \sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{k^2}}{k}+\sum_{k=n}^{\infty }\frac{x^{k^2}}{k}\right ]=\\=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{k=-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{x^{k^2}}{k}=0\Rightarrow S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{3}{4}\zeta (2)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{align}

Is this true for all real $x$?

@Anne Bauval
Two sums covers k from -infinity to +infinity except $k=0$.  Since  the summand is odd in K so it vanished

@Sahaj $1>x>0$.

I hastened with restrictions. Yes, I solved for any $x$

The summand is odd in k, sum from -infinity to +infinity must be zero

Again:  therefore, $\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{k^2}}{k}+\sum_{k=n}^{\infty }\frac{x^{k^2}}{k}$ cannot be equal to that sum.

Then what is it equal to?

The first sum is from n-1 to - infinity.  Or form - infinity to n-1. Everything must be right!

If so, you should write $-\infty$ instead of $\infty$ for the first sum.

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{x^{(j-n)^2}-x^{(j-1+n)^2}}{2j-1}$$
$$=\sum_{k=1-n}^\infty\frac{x^{k^2}}{2k+2n-1}-\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{x^{k^2}}{2k-2n+1}$$
$$=\sum_{k=1-n}^{n-1}\frac{x^{k^2}}{2k+2n-1}+\sum_{k=n}^\infty x^{k^2}\left(\frac1{2k+2n-1}-\frac1{2k-2n+1}\right)$$
$$=\frac1{2n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k^2}\left(\frac1{2k+2n-1}-\frac1{2k-2n+1}\right)$$
$$=\frac1{2n-1}+2(2n-1)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{k^2}}{(2n-1)^2-4k^2}.$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{x^{(j-n)^2}-x^{(j-1+n)^2}}{2j-1}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{k^2}}{(2n-1)^2-4k^2}$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}8+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2-4k^2}$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}8,$$
since
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2-4k^2}=\frac\pi{8k}\tan(k\pi)=0.$$

This is not what I wanted. Thanks for the solution, but it seems you are doing almost the same thing as me. I wanted to see if there was an exotic solution? Wrote in my question
